# How can i make a prefix so i can address a folder in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, prefix

I always have problems making new prefixes in xaml. Most of the time, i get the message that the URI cannot be found in the assembly. My setup:

I have a WPF project (in a solution with class libs and asp.NET projects) with a MainWindow.xaml file. The XAML starts with : Window x:Class="MainWindow" ... .
So as default, there's no namespace given to it. In that same project i made a folder "Folder". In that folder, i have resx-files. What i need to do is make a prefix in xaml so i can address those files. I was thinking of :

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.Folder"
```

and then for my controls

```
<Label Content="{x:Static p:NameResxFile.KeyName></Label>
```

However, the prefix generates the "URI cannot be found in the assembly" error. I'm i just failing at making prefixes?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

If you cannot make a namespace ref to a folder, what is happening [here](http://robertoschiabel.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/wpf-add-localization-via-resx-files/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xmlns` specifies namespaces, it does not bother with folders or files, if you need access to an external resource you can load it into your control's resources via `ResourceDictionary`.

There was something like this i think:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="ExternalRes" Source="Folder/File.xaml"/>
    ....
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference an element of resource dictionary you should add that dictionary to your control's `Resources` collection or register it in the `App.xaml` file. After that you could just use [StaticResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx) extension to get access to the element. Your code will look like this:

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="/Folder/NameResxFile.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <!-- ... -->
  <Label Content="{StaticResource KeyName}"/>
```

Things get trickier if you want to put the resource dictionary to another assembly and reference it. For this purpose refer to [PackURIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) article.